# How to get time by timezone, that gives in OpenWatherMap API response. Python

Tags: python, time, openweathermap

I'm get information about current weather in some city via request to OWM API:

```
response = requests.get(
    f'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city}&appid={KEY}&units=metric')

content = json.loads(response.text)
weather_info = {'degrees': f"{content['main']['temp']}",
                'state': f"{content['weather'][0]['main']}",
                'city': f"{content['name']}",
                'timezone': f"{content['timezone']}",
                'id': f"{city.id}"}
```

Wheh I print `weather_info` in get this JSON response (e.g city is New York):

```
{'degrees': '9.64', 'state': 'Clouds', 'city': 'New York', 'timezone': '-14400', 'id': '2'}
```

So how can I get current time in New York by timezone that gives in this response (`'timezone': '-14400'`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with `datetime`:

```
import datetime 

def get_date(timezone):
    tz = datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=int(timezone)))
    return datetime.datetime.now(tz = tz).strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S") #strftime is just for visually formatting the datetime object

weather_info = {'degrees': f"{content['main']['temp']}",
                'state': f"{content['weather'][0]['main']}",
                'city': f"{content['name']}",
                'timezone': f"{get_date(content['timezone'])}",
                'id': f"{city.id}"}
```